# How do I use find command with pipe in bash?

Tags: bash

The directory structure looks like

```
home
--dir1_foo
----subdirectory.....
--dir2_foo
--dir3_foo
--dir4_bar
--dir5_bar
```

I'm trying to use 'find' command to get directories containing specific strings first, (in this case 'foo'), then use 'find' command again to retrieve some directories matching conditions.

So, I first tried

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in `find ./ -type d -name "*foo*" `;
do
    for subdir in `find $dir -mindepth 2 -type d `;
    do
       [Do some jobs]
    done
done
```

, and this script works fine.

Then I thought that using only one loop with pipe like below would also work, but this does not work

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in `find ./ -type d -name "*foo*" | find -mindepth 2 -type d `;
do
   [Do some jobs]
done
```

and actually this script works the same as

```
for dir in `find -mindepth 2 -type d`;
do
   [Do some jobs]
done
```

, which means that the first find command is ignored..

What is the problem?

Comment: Try to avoid it, if you can. Either use the `-exec` primary to run a script that contains your commands, or try to use pathname expansion instead. In this case, it looks like you could just use `for dir in *foo*/ */*foo*/; do` to get the same directories your `find` command would, with the benefit of working with *any* legal directory name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your script is doing is not a good practice and has lot of potential pitfalls. See [BashFAQ- Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) to understand why.

You can use `xargs` with `-0` to read null delimited files and use the another `find` command without needing to use the for-loop

```
find ./ -type d -name "*foo*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{.} find {.} -mindepth 2 -type d
```

The string following `-I` in `xargs` acts like a placeholder for the input received from the previous pipeline and passes it to the next command. The `-print0` option is GNU specific which is a safe option to hande filenames/directory names containing spaces or any other shell meta-characters.

So with the above command in-place, if you are interested in doing some action over the output from 2nd command, do a process-substitution syntax with the `while` command,

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
    echo "$f"
    # Your other actions can be done on "$f" here
done < <(find ./ -type d -name "*foo*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{.} find {.} -mindepth 2 -type d -print0)
```

As far the reason why your pipelines using find won't work is that you are *not* reading the previous find command's output. You needed either `xargs` or `-execdir` while the latter is not an option I would recommend.